# Node 15 and 16 hang when import 'react-dom' module

Tags: reactjs, jsdom

For testing purpose, I've the following script where I try to import react-dom using a jsdom.

```
const {JSDOM} = require('jsdom');
const dom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html>');

global.window = dom.window;
global.navigator = dom.window.navigator;
global.document = dom.window.document;

require('raf').polyfill();
require('react-dom');
console.log('React dom imported')
```

It works fine with Node v14.17.0, but for v15.14.0 and v16.2.0 the script never ends, `React dom imported` is always printed in the console, so it looks that some resource is still in use and the script never completes because of this.

If I remove  'react-dom' require everything works fine in every version.

The issue appears at MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)

Comment: Maybe try using [`why-is-node-running`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/why-is-node-running)?

Comment: This is also happening for me both with Node v16.2.0 and v14.16.1

I'm using an intel-based MacBook Pro 13-inch 2019 with macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: why is node-running says: There are 4 handle(s) keeping the process running

# MESSAGEPORT 
node:internal/async_hooks:200

/Users/alasarr/test-dom/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:178 - var channel = new MessageChannel();